# Is vlookup the correct thing to do to have the results next row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a vlookup to look for the all cells in the column D and see if they got a positive match in the C cells. If yes, I'm putting what is in the B cell next to the C cell.

In the example below, E2 will have what is inside of B2 after a lookup on D2 in the C column.

I've tried this formula but it is not the good one

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,C:C,0,FALSE)
```

I hope I don't need VBA

Best.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear exactly what you are looking for.  I think you are trying to lookup data in column B based on a key in column C.  If so what you want to use is

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,C:C,0))
```

As a breakdown, the `MATCH` will return a number representing which row within the range `C:C` matches the key `D2`.  And, `INDEX` returns the element in `B:B` at row `MATCH(D2,C:C,0)`.